# How to add 'res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")' in express js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, httprequest, access-control

In my app I use angularjs and cordova for front-end and express and node js for backend which is acting as server. My client side is running on http://localhost:9000 but, my express js is running on http://localhost:3000. I need to get data from express API. While accessing, it says '

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/data. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

For this, i need to add `res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")`. It is to access one domain from other domain. How to add this header in express js? Please, help me out..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also started learning about this and while searching I found related to this.

Access-Control-Allow-Origin only accepts * or a single origin.

If you want to support multiple origins but not all of them, then you must:

look at the Origin request header
check if it is on your list of acceptable origins
put it in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header

See this if it could be helpful to you.

[No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' - Node / Apache Port Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310394/no-access-control-allow-origin-node-apache-port-issue)