# How to send a cross-domain POST request using ajax call in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, cross-domain, asp.net-web-api

I am developing an application in which from a website project I give a call to web api method using ajax call javascript. When I run both projects locally it works fine, but when I do publish web api project on demo site the ajax call does not reach to the web api method.
My ajax call is as follows-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <title></title>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
   var url = 'http://abc.demo.in/c60/api/Patient/Create/';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: getData(),
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    alert("success")
                },
                error: function (result) {
                            alert('POST failed.');
                        }
            });

            function getData() {
                var patient = new Object();
                patient.Name = "Mugdha";
                patient.Gender = "Female";
                patient.Email = "mugdhaShenoy@yahoo.co.in";
                patient.Mobile = "";
                patient.BloodGroup = "AB+";
                patient.MedicalHistory = "High BP, Cholosterol, Diebetis";
                patient.Allergy = "Dust, wind";
                patient.EmergencyContactName = "Riya Sahani";
                patient.EmergencyContactNo = "9988990200";
                patient.ProfileImage = "";
                patient.FormNo = "92";
                patient.BirthDate = new Date(1989, 09, 08).toISOString();
                return patient;
            }

</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

When I try to reach the api domain(which is on different server) I have faced an error as -

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://abc.demo.in/c60/api/Patient/Create/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:49370' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Is there any solution for this? I have added `CorsHandler.cs` file in my webapi project.

Comment: See my answer in this post if it could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466380/how-to-add-res-addheaderaccess-control-allow-origin-in-express-js/29466458#29466458

Comment: You also need to setup crossDomain: true in ajax if you have used CorsHandler.cs

Comment: Also need to register a Cross-Domain handler in our application. So open the Global.asax file and put the following lines for the Application_Start() event.
 
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new CorsHandler());

Comment: I already have `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new CorsHandler());` in my `Application_Start()` and also tried with setting up `crossDomain: true` in ajax but still does not working

Comment: have you added setup crossDomain:true in ajax

Comment: yes.. the code for ajax is as
`var url = 'http://abc.demo.in/c60/api/Patient/Create/';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: getData(),
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json",
                crossDomain: true ,
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    alert("success")
                },
                error: function (result) {
                            alert('POST failed.');
                        }
            });`

Comment: But in your code pasted above I can't see this setup

Comment: I have made appropriate changes in ajax call..but still having same issue..What I'm doing wrong?