# I can not access in to a server with angularJs ($ http)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, cors, angular-ui-router

through AngularJs'm trying to access a server to make me return a JSON in thi way

```
modulo.controller('listaController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?[apyKeyBlaBla]&q=Toy+Story+3&page_limit=1').success(function(data) {
        $scope.items = data;
    });
});
```

but when you launch the application I get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load [Name Sting] No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8383' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Where is the solution?
Notified that I use netbeans and I put my apyKey in the above string then the string is correct because I tested it!

Comment: See the post in this .. you will get some idea from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466380/how-to-add-res-addheaderaccess-control-allow-origin-in-express-js/29466458#29466458

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
$http.jsonp('http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?[apyKeyBlaBla]&q=Toy+Story+3&page_limit=1&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data) {
    $scope.items = data;
});
```

Important is to have **callback=JSON_CALLBACK** in the request url

Answer (score 0):

This error is raised because browsers does not allow to make AJAX request from one host (localhost) to another host (rottentomatoes.com) unless the later permits so. This is known as [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

The only way you may accomplish this is to use a gateway between your AJAX code and rottentomatoes.com. e.i. Make the AJAX request to a backend app you wrote and let the later make the actual request to rottentomatoes.com returning the result to your cleint application.

Comment: What's the code that i must write? In this way I don't understand!

Answer (score -1):

"You are doing an XMLHttpRequest to a different domain than your page is on. So the browser is blocking it as it usually allows a request in the same origin for security reasons. You need to do something different when you want to do a cross-domain request." by @MD. Sahib Bin Mahboob

I suggest you reading this question/answers:

["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: What's the code that i must write? In this way I don't understand! I understand the problema but i don't understand like resolve it...

Comment: Does the rottentomatoes api service has JSONP turned on?